# OpenCV: how to check if an image contains a grid?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm new to programming and opencv, and I'm trying to write a python script with a function that returns True if a given image contains a grid (a table) or False if it does not.
I don't need the position of the grid, just to know if the image contains one.
Here it is a sample image to process, but I'd like the script to work with (almost) every type of image.
I don't have any idea of logical steps to follow, so thanks to anyone who can help me

[image: 1]

I tried to find the contours of the table and to overwrite them, but I don't know how could I check if these contours are an actual table.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("img.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

count = 0

for cnt in contours:
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * perimeter, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        count = count + 1

cv2.imwrite('output.png', image)
print(count)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And this is the output.

[image: 2]

Comment: As a first step you could use horizontal and vertical erosion to filter out all contours that are not either horizontally or vertically alligned. Similar tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html

Comment: I think, the word "grid" has infinite degree of freedom(size, color, rotation, etc...).
You say "every type of image", but some definition about "grid" to be recoginized will be necessary. If "grid" can be rotated, using some method using words like "Horizontal", "Vertical" may be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your grid is axis-aligned?! Then a simple approach would be to apply a Hough transform to find the lines, filter them by angle and count intersections. This could be a first good metric. You can repeat this for multiple angles.

Here is a simple python snippet (adapted from the OpenCV [Hough Line Transform Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)):

```
import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def min_angle_difference(angle1, angle2):
    diff = (angle1 - angle2) % (2 * math.pi)
    return min(diff, 2 * math.pi - diff)


def is_line_at_angle(l, angle, threshold=math.pi/18):
    dx = l[2] - l[0]
    dy = l[3] - l[1]

    # rotating an line by 180 degrees does not change anything
    angle_l = math.atan2(dy, dx) % math.pi

    return min_angle_difference(angle_l, angle) < threshold


def main():        
    filename = 'pnZxP.jpg'

    # Loads an image
    src = cv.imread(filename, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    dst = cv.Canny(src, 50, 200, None, 3)
    
    # Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
    cdst = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        
    # probabilistic Hough transform algorithm for line detection
    linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)

    # Filter lines according to their angle
    horizontal_lines = [l[0] for l in linesP if is_line_at_angle(l[0], 0, math.pi/18)]
    vertical_lines = [l[0] for l in linesP if is_line_at_angle(l[0], math.pi/2, math.pi/18)]
    
    # Draw the lines
    for l in horizontal_lines:        
        cv.line(cdst, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    for l in vertical_lines:        
        cv.line(cdst, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,255,0), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    # Counting intersections
    intersections = 0
    for h_line in horizontal_lines:
        for v_line in vertical_lines:
            if (min(h_line[0], h_line[2]) <= v_line[0] <= max(h_line[0], h_line[2])) and \
            (min(v_line[1], v_line[3]) <= h_line[1] <= max(v_line[1], v_line[3])):
                intersections += 1

    print('Nr of intersections: ', intersections)    
    cv.imshow("Probabilistic Line Transform", cdst)
    
    cv.waitKey()
    return 0
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```